# How to get closed form from generating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions, closed-form

I have this generating function:

$$\frac{1}{2}\, \left( {\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-4\,z}}}-1 \right)  \left( \,{
\frac {1-\sqrt {1-4\,z}}{2z}}-1 \right)$$

and I know that $\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-4\,z}}$ is the generating function for the sequence $\binom {2n} {n}$, and $\frac {1-\sqrt {1-4\,z}}{2z}$ is the generating function for the sequence $\frac {1}{n+1}\binom{2n} {n}$.

Now, I thought that I could substitute those in there, and where they multiply I'll use a summation like this:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left( 1-\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n} {n}-\binom{2n} {n} + 
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k+1} \binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k}
\right)$$

Could this be right? It doesn't seem to work when I try in Maple. What else could I do?

I already know that the end sequence will be $\binom{2n-1}{n-2}$ if this can help...

Comment: Be careful with your terminology: everywhere that you’ve written *series*, you should have *sequence*.

Comment: yep..I fixed it!

Comment: Note that $1$ (the constant function) is not the generating function for $1$ (the constant sequence), but rather for $\delta_{n}$ (the sequence with $a_0=1$ and $a_{n>0}=0$).

Comment: uh.. that's right. So what should I put there? some function of n that gives 1 on n=0 and 0 the rest of the time? What function is that?

Comment: @Adam: I like the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) for that purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding the product, and after some algebra:
$$
   g(z) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-4 z}-1}{z}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 z}}+1\right)
$$
Using generalized binomial theorem:
$$
   [z]^n g(z) = \frac{1}{2} \left(  \delta_{n,0} + \binom{1/2}{n+1} (-4)^{n+1} + \binom{-1/2}{n} (-4)^n \right)
$$
Using 
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \binom{-1/2}{n}  - 4 \binom{1/2}{n+1} &=& \frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{n! \Gamma(1/2-n)} - \frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{(n+1)! \Gamma(1/2-n)} \\ 
 &=& (-1)^n (n-1) \frac{\Gamma(1/2+n) \Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(1/2) (n+1)!n!} \\ 
 &=& (-1)^n (n-1) \frac{(2n)!}{4^n (n+1)!n!} \\ 
  &=& (-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!}{2 \cdot 4^{n-1} (n+1)!(n-2)!} = 2 \cdot \frac{(-1)^n}{4^n} \cdot \binom{2n-1}{n+1}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Hence, using Iverson's bracket:
$$
   [z]^n g(z) = \binom{2n-1}{n+1}  \left[ n \ge 2 \right]
$$

Answer (score 3):

It’s not necessary to use the generalized binomial theorem and the gamma function. Let $$g(x)=\frac12\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}-1\right) \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}-1\right)$$ and $u=\sqrt{1-4x}$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
g(x)&= \frac12\left(\frac1u-1\right)\left(\frac{1-u}{2x}-1\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{1-u}{2xu}-\frac{1-u}{2x}-\frac1u+1\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac1{2xu}-\frac1x+\frac{u}{2x}-\frac1u+1\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{1+u^2}{2xu}-\frac1x-\frac1u+1\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{1-2x}{xu}-\frac1x-\frac1u+1\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac1{xu}-\frac1x-\frac3u+1\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac1x\left(\frac1u-1\right)+1-\frac3u\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{k\ge 1}\binom{2k}k x^{k-1}+1-3\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{2k}k x^k\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(1+\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\binom{2k+2}{k+1}-3\binom{2k}k\right)x^k\right)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k\ge 2}\left(\binom{2k+2}{k+1}-3\binom{2k}k\right)x^k.
\end{align*}$$

Now

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{2k+2}{k+1}-3\binom{2k}k&=\binom{2k+1}k+\binom{2k+1}{k+1}-3\binom{2k}k\\
&=\binom{2k+1}k+\binom{2k}k+\binom{2k}{k-1}-3\binom{2k}k\\
&=\binom{2k+1}k+\binom{2k}{k+1}-2\binom{2k}k\\
&=\binom{2k}{k-1}+\binom{2k}k+\binom{2k}{k+1}-2\binom{2k}k\\
&=\binom{2k}{k-1}-\binom{2k}k+\binom{2k}{k+1}\\
&=\binom{2k}{k-1}-\binom{2k}k+\binom{2k-1}k+\binom{2k-1}{k+1}\\
&=\binom{2k}{k-1}-\binom{2k-1}{k-1}-\binom{2k-1}k+\binom{2k-1}k+\binom{2k-1}{k+1}\\
&=\binom{2k}{k-1}-\binom{2k-1}{k-1}+\binom{2k-1}{k+1}\\
&=\binom{2k-1}{k-2}+\binom{2k-1}{k+1}\\
&=2\binom{2k-1}{k-2},
\end{align*}$$

so $\displaystyle[x^k]g(x)=\binom{2k-1}{k-2}$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Expand out the product, and look at what each term is the generating function for.

Answer (score 1):

With  this  type  of  problem  Lagrange  inversion  is  the  preferred
approach. Suppose we seek to extract coefficients from
$$Q(z) = \frac{1}{2}
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}-1\right)
\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}-1\right).$$

The closed form for the coefficients is
$$[z^n] Q(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{2}
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}-1\right)
\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}-1\right) \; dz.$$

Now put $1-4z=w^2$ so that $1/4-z=1/4 \times w^2$ or $z=1/4\times(1-w^2)$ 
and $dz = -1/2 \times w\; dw.$
This gives for the integral
$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{w}{4}
\frac{4^{n+1}}{(1-w^2)^{n+1}}
\left(\frac{1}{w}-1\right)
\left(\frac{1-w}{2\times 1/4\times(1-w^2)}-1\right) \; dw
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{4^n}{(1-w^2)^{n+1}}
(1-w)
\left(\frac{2}{1+w}-1\right) \; dw
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{4^n}{(1-w)^n (1+w)^{n+1}}
\left(\frac{2}{1+w}-1\right) \; dw
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{4^n}{(1-w)^n (1+w)^{n+1}}
\frac{1-w}{1+w} \; dw
\\ = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{4^n}{(1-w)^{n-1} (1+w)^{n+2}} \; dw.$$

Prepare for coefficient extraction.
$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon}
\frac{4^n}{(1-w)^{n-1} (2+(w-1))^{n+2}} \; dw
\\= -\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon} \frac{4^n}{2^{n+2}}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^{n-1} (1+(w-1)/2)^{n+2}} \; dw
\\= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\epsilon} 2^{n-2} 
\frac{(-1)^n}{(w-1)^{n-1}}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {q+n+1\choose n+1} (-1)^q
\frac{(w-1)^q}{2^q} \; dw.$$

We need the coefficient $[(w-1)^{n-2}]$ which is
$$2^{n-2} (-1)^n {n-2+n+1\choose n+1} (-1)^{n-2} 
\frac{1}{2^{n-2}} = {2n-1\choose n+1}$$
or alternatively
$${2n-1\choose n-2}.$$